# Is it possible to change every column name in R?

Tags: r

Hello I’m new to learning R, I’m currently working on a project in which at one point I needed to change my column names to make them easier to work with. I hard coded each one because my data only had 15 columns. However, I’m wondering if I was working on a much larger data set, say 50-100+ columns, it would seem tedious to hard code each one. I’m wondering is there a simpler way to change every column name in a table rather than hard code every name?

For example:

```
colnames(data)[1] = "X-1"
colnames(data)[2] = "X-2"
colnames(data)[3] = "X-3" 
colnames(data)[N] = "X-N"
```

Comment: Why not? Seems pretty identical to me

Comment: I was speaking in regards to akrun's answer, I apologize for the confusion. I had searched for "change every column name in R" but did not see the one you pointed out show in search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `paste`

```
colnames(data) <- paste("X-", seq_along(data), sep="")
```

It may be better to use underscore (`_`) as the delimiter

```
colnames(data) <- paste("X_", seq_along(data), sep="")
```

Comment: why not `paste("X", seq_along(data), sep="-")` ? (or if empty string for `sep`, better use `paste0`)

Comment: @Cath It's okay.  My point was the `paste` is more general compared to `paste0`.  Regarding using `sep="_"` or `sep=""`, is a combination somebody can work with.  I should have used `sep="-"`, but I came up with this and find a comment from RS, so didn't bother to change